# Is it possible to iterate a list calling async function

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio

I'm new to this so I apologize for mistakes

I'm trying to figure out a way to iterate inside a for loop range, calling an async function but without waiting for a response

here's my code

```
import asyncio
from random import randint
import time
import threading

async def print_i(i):
   number = 0 
   if (number % 2) == 0: #check for even number
      time.sleep(5)
   while number != 5:
      number = randint(0,100)
   print("id-", i)

for i in range (0,100):
   asyncio.run(print_i(i))
   # thread = threading.Thread(target=print_i(i))
   # thread.start()
```

Both the `asyncio.run` and the `thread.start()` are linearly executing the called function, whereas i was hoping that the for loop would call the functions in all iterations in one go, and only the even numbers of "i" would get the `time.sleep(5)`

Is this possible?

Comment: ``threading.Thread(target=print_i, args=(i,))``

Comment: Number will always be 0 when you are checking for it.

Comment: `time.sleep` is not how an async function should sleep. That's a blocking call. It'll completely halt the event loop for the duration of the sleep.

Comment: Note that there's no point to making the function ``async`` (and the ``Thread`` won't work properly if it is ``async``). You need ``async`` if you ``await`` something, and in return you *must* ``await`` specific things (e.g. ``await asyncio.sleep(5)`` instead of just ``time.sleep(5)``). But ``async`` is a difficult beast and you already have several regular concurrency blunders, so it's perhaps a good idea just to forget about ``async`` for now.

Comment: i did remove the "async" from the function when i used thread after it thrown an error

Answer (score 3):

Here's some basic examples I made about how to achieve concurrency in `asyncio`, `threading`, and `trio`. Consider `range()` call as `list` in these cases.

If you wonder why the `trio`, there's a better alternative to `asyncio` - called [Structured Concurrency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_concurrency) - and they use different method when spawning a concurrent task - you might stumble on it one day.

For asyncio:

```py
import asyncio


async def task(num: int):
    print(f"task {num} started.")

    # async function need something 'awaitable' to be asynchronous
    await asyncio.sleep(3)

    print(f"task {num} finished.")


async def spawn_task():
    task_list = []

    for n in range(5):
        task_list.append(asyncio.create_task(task(n)))

    await asyncio.gather(*task_list)


asyncio.run(spawn_task())
```

For threading:

```py
import threading
import time


def thread_workload(num: int):
    print(f"task {num} started.")

    # most of python's IO functions (including time.sleep) release GIL,
    # allowing other thread to run.
    # GIL prevents more than 1 thread running the python code.
    time.sleep(3)

    print(f"task {num} finished.")


def spawn_thread():
    for n in range(5):
        t = threading.Thread(target=thread_workload, args=(n,))
        t.start()


spawn_thread()
```

For Trio:

```py
import trio


async def task(num: int):
    print(f"task {num} started.")

    # async function need something 'awaitable' to be asynchronous
    await trio.sleep(3)

    print(f"task {num} finished.")


async def spawn_task():
    async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
        # explicit task spawning area. Nursery for tasks!

        for n in range(5):
            nursery.start_soon(task, n)


trio.run(spawn_task)
```

Output:

```
task 0 started.
task 1 started.
task 2 started.
task 3 started.
task 4 started.
task 0 finished.
task 1 finished.
task 2 finished.
task 3 finished.
task 4 finished.
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies so far everyone.
Specifically this: 
"Consider 'range()' call as list in these cases." what do you mean by this?

Comment: Your question title says "Iterate List" - So I wanted to explicitly say that I'm using range where actual List should be in